# Change logging level dynamically in spring boot app

Tags: java, spring, logging, spring-boot

I have a spring boot app where I provide logging configuration using

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:E:\workspace\log4j.properties
```

I am using slf4j for logging. Is there any way in which I can just change "log4j.rootLogger" property and log level can be changed dynamically. If not then what should be the best approach to do that in which I can have minimal change in code. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure monitorInterval in your log4j configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration monitorInterval="30">
...
</Configuration>
```

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html

Log4j will automatically detect changes to the configuration file and reconfigure itself.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about this.